# function that returns object names

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, javascript-objects, higher-order-functions

```
const parks = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Acadia",
      areaInSquareKm: 198.6,
      location: { state: "Maine" },
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Canyonlands",
      areaInSquareKm: 1366.2,
      location: { state: "Utah" },
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Crater Lake",
      areaInSquareKm: 741.5,
      location: { state: "Oregon" },
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Lake Clark",
      areaInSquareKm: 10602,
      location: { state: "Alaska" },
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: "Kenai Fjords",
      areaInSquareKm: 2710,
      location: { state: "Alaska" },
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      name: "Zion",
      areaInSquareKm: 595.9,
      location: { state: "Utah" },
    },
  ];

  const users = {
    "karah.branch3": {
      visited: [1],
      wishlist: [4, 6],
    },
    "dwayne.m55": {
      visited: [2, 5, 1],
      wishlist: [],
    },
    thiagostrong1: {
      visited: [5],
      wishlist: [6, 3, 2],
    },
    "don.kim1990": {
      visited: [2, 6],
      wishlist: [1],
    },
  };
```

I need to create a function that does this: This function returns all the usernames who have visited any park on the given user's wishlist.

```
getUsersForUserWishlist(users, "karah.branch3"); //> ["dwayne.m55"]
getUsersForUserWishlist(users, "dwayne.m55"); //> []
```

This is what I have so far but it doesn't work:

```
function getUsersForUserWishlist(users, userId) {
  let wish = userId.wishlist;
  return users[userId].visited.map((visited) => wish.includes(visited));
}
```

Please keep in mind: I just finished a section of my course that covers advanced functions (find, filter, map, some, every, forEach) and I'm supposed to use them to solve the problem.

Comment: I'm struggling to see the logic here. Can you explain why `["dwayne.m55"]` is the expected output for the `karah.branch3`. Based on your description of the function "This function returns all the usernames who have visited any park on the given user's wishlist", I would expect it to be `["don.kim1990"]`, as dom.kim1990 has visited park 6, which is in Karah's wishlist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go over what you tried:

```
let wish = userId.wishlist;
```

Here, `userId` is a string. A string has no property `wishlist`. You need to get the user Object corresponding to that ID: `users[userId].wishlist`. Just like you did on the second line:

```
users[userId].visited.map((visited) => wish.includes(visited));
```

However, [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is not the best method for what you want to achieve. You want to [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the user names to keep only the ones that pass a condition. Which is that [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) parks in the wishlist  are [`included`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) in that user's list of visited parks:

```js
const users= {
  "karah.branch3": { visited: [1], wishlist: [4,6] },
  "dwayne.m55": { visited: [2,5,1], wishlist: [] },
  "thiagostrong1": { visited: [5], wishlist: [6,3,2] },
  "don.kim1990": { visited: [2,6], wishlist: [1] }
};

function getUsersForUserWishlist(users, userId) {
  const wishlist = users[userId].wishlist;
  // Get all user names
  return Object.keys(users)
    // Filter them
    .filter(
      // If the wishlist has some elements which that user has visited
      name => wishlist.some(park => users[name].visited.includes(park))
    );
}

console.log(getUsersForUserWishlist(users, "karah.branch3")); //> ["don.kim1990"]
console.log(getUsersForUserWishlist(users, "dwayne.m55")); //> []
```

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! I had forgotten all about Object.keys()